# Facebook graph api upload photo error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload, photo

i have this code...

```
require_once "facebook.php";
$app_id = "xxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    "appId" => $app_id,
    "secret" => $app_secret,
    "cookie" => true
));

$random_file = rand();

copy('http://alylores.x10.mx/gd/clean2/pic.php', 'temp/'.$random_file.'.jpg');
$img = realpath("temp/".$random_file.".jpg");
// allow uploads
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
// add a photo
$photo = $facebook->api("/".$_POST['fid']."/photos?access_token=".$_POST['foauth'],"POST",
    array(
            "source" => "@" . $img,
            "message" => "This photo came from my app."
    )
);



echo "<script type='text/javascript'>parent.iframe_callback();</script>";

unlink('temp/'.$random_file.'.jpg');
```

i'm trying to upload a photo into user's photos from an **IFRAME**.... facebook `id` and `oauth_token` are passed using post request from the parent window..

and when i check... it returns this....

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. 
thrown in /home/alylores/public_html/gd/clean2/base_facebook.php on line 1033
```

but when i check if the `oauth_token` exists by `echo()`
the `oauth_token` does exist....

can someone help me work this out please???

Comment: array(
        "access_token" => $_POST["foauth"],
        "source" => "@" . $img,
        "message" => "This photo came from my app."
    )

Comment: I think that the php sdk adds the access token itself and so there's no need to you to add it to the request path. Just try *$facebook->api('/'.$_POST['fid'].'photos')*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array( "access_token" => $_POST["foauth"], "source" => "@" . $img, "message" => "This photo     came from my app." )
```